# images not showing up after changing the web folder to public_html

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

When moving my project onto a new server, I was required to change the public folder from web to public_html.  In addition, I wanted the symfony public files to be in a public folder, public_html/symfony.  So they would be accessed by going to the website www.mysite.com/symfony

This was achieved by:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
    $this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir()."public_html/symfony")
```

in one of my custom forms, I directly call some images to be displayed using

```
$this->renderContentTag('image','',array('src' => '/images/'.$object->getImageSrc()))
```

On my new server it is looking for the images in  home/user/public_html/images/image1.gif instead of in the public_html/symfony directory that I thought I specified.

I don't want to have to change my custom form because I want to be able to change the sub folder easily.  Why do my images point to public_html instead of public_html/symfony?  I clearly misunderstood what setWebDir() does and any insight would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that renderContentTag() won't recognize src for what it is : it is too general.
I think it'll work fine if you use the image_tag() method.

Comment: called from inside a widget:

    image_tag('/images/'.$object->get..

worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the src value for an image use the helper:

```
image_path('/images/'.$object->getImageSrc());
```